# jQuery/PHP image slider that loads user selected image directories

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, server-side, server-side-scripting

I'm looking for an image slider that has the ability to load different directories via my server. I'm not using any CMS.

For example if I have the directories: `localhost/galleries/florida`, `localhost/galleries/wedding`, and `localhost/galleries/graduation`

When the user visits my site they will see the image slider (with just a place holder image) and a few links with different gallery titles. The user can then click the link to select a gallery to view from. In this case it's, Florida, Wedding, or Graduation when clicked it loads the directory into the slider (without a page reload).

Are there any image sliders that come with a server side script I can customize for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Slidedeck](http://developers.slidedeck.com/). It believe it will meet your requirements.  Otherwise [this page](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/02/jquery-image-slider-plugins.html) has a number of jQuery options.